# SQL Server 2008 Express advanced services

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I’ve setup SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services before on a domain machine..  Now… I’m trying to setup a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Advanced Services on a windows 7 box that s not part of domain, but rather about 5 computers all running in the same workgroup. How do you setup RS so that these people can get to the reports. It prompts for a user id and pw, but even the administrator account on the RS box won’t go through. I’ve tried several different combo’s in the config using both a built in services and even then administrator account just to see if I can get the RS to be accessed. Trying to get RS up for a non profit that I thought I would help out.. not being so helpful just yet.

Anyway.. any words of advice out there from someone who has done RS on a non domain env.

Also.. do I remember correctly… 2008 uses it’s own web service.. so I don’t need to have IIS installed on the box.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried logging in using COMPUTERNAME\UserName where COMPUTERNAME is where the SQL Express is Installed

Comment: yes i have and still no luck getting into the report browser interface. I've not published any reports to it yet.. just trying to get the interface to come up on the windows 7 RS "Server".